# How to configure an ActiveMQ Artemis queue not be created again

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have an embedded ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 broker that has no pre-configured queues. I'd like for the client to connect to the broker and have its queue created automatically if it doesn't exist. This works just fine the 1st time when I run the client but on the second time I connect again to the broker the client throws an error :

```
errorType=QUEUE_EXISTS message=AMQ229019: Queue hornetq already exists on address router
```

Is it possible to configure the client or the server in such a way that if a queue is already in existence it should not attempt to recreate it again?

Below are the programs I am running:

**Server**

```java
try {
    ActiveMQServer server = new ActiveMQServerImpl(new ConfigurationImpl()
         .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
         .setBindingsDirectory("./router/data/bindings")
         .setLargeMessagesDirectory("./router/data/large")
         .setPagingDirectory("./router/data/paging")
         .setJournalDirectory("./router/data/journal")
         .setSecurityEnabled(false)
         .addAcceptorConfiguration("tcp", "tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?protocols=CORE,AMQP"));
    server.start();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

**Client**

```java
ServerLocator serverLocator = ActiveMQClient.createServerLocator("tcp://127.0.0.1.3:61617");
ClientSessionFactory factory = serverLocator.createSessionFactory();
ClientSession session = factory.createSession();
session.createQueue(new QueueConfiguration("router::hornetq")
        .setAutoCreateAddress(Boolean.FALSE)
        .setAutoCreated(Boolean.FALSE)
        .setRoutingType(RoutingType.ANYCAST));
ClientProducer producer = session.createProducer("router::hornetq");
ClientMessage message = session.createMessage(true);
message.getBodyBuffer().writeString("Core Queue Message");
producer.send(message);
session.start();
ClientConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer("router::hornetq");
ClientMessage msgReceived = consumer.receive();
System.out.println("message = " + msgReceived.getBodyBuffer().readString());
session.close();
```

I'm using the fully qualified queue name here (i.e. `router::hornetq`) because I have multiple queues on the `router` address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client is using the **core** API which is a low-level API that does not support auto-queue creation. Your client is creating (or attempting to create) the queue manually, e.g.:

```java
session.createQueue(new QueueConfiguration("router::hornetq")
        .setAutoCreateAddress(Boolean.FALSE)
        .setAutoCreated(Boolean.FALSE)
        .setRoutingType(RoutingType.ANYCAST));
```

The exception you're seeing is no doubt being thrown here if the queue exists already. Creating a queue is not idempotent so you have 3 options from what I can see:

- Simply catch the `ActiveMQQueueExistsException` that is being thrown here and ignore it.
- Use `ClientSession.queueQuery` to see if the queue exists before you attempt to create it. If it exists then don't try to create it again. If it doesn't exist then create it. That said, if you have lots of clients like this running concurrently it's still possible you could get an `ActiveMQQueueExistsException` due to race conditions between the clients.
- Use a client/protocol that supports auto-creation like the core JMS client or AMQP.

---

A few other things are worth mentioning:

- Since you're not explicitly calling `ClientSession.createAddress()` you probably want to use `setAutoCreateAddress(Boolean.TRUE)`.
- Your consumer doesn't *have* to use `router::hornetq`. It can just use `hornetq` and it will receive any messages sent to the `hornetq` queue. Queue names are universally unique in the broker.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I wonder if the lack of idempotency on core API is by design or is this something that can be looked into ?
As for the queue name, I have 2 queues under the same address hence the explicit naming.

Comment: The lack idempotency is by design, although that's not to say the design couldn't change. The server API has a `createQueue` with a flag to ignore the call if the queue already exists.

Comment: Noted. One more question, we have been using hornetq for the longest and now we are looking to migrate to artemis. We were using core APIS but we would like to embrace  AMQP to accommodate more microservices in different langs, is there a notable performance difference ?

Comment: That's really a completely different question from the one you originally asked. I recommend you create a new question for the core vs. AMQP performance issue.

Comment: hehe I had to try though but I understand. Thanks

Comment: For anyone with this issue in future I  went with the 1st option, Its the simplest and elegant in my own opinion since it doesn't involve alot of moving parts. Find the solution https://gist.github.com/kimathie/ffc344c6d59de2b5782f570a22f74d10

Comment: I put a comment on that gist that may be helpful.